# Google Map API on release apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api, google-maps

im using google api on my app with android studio.
i added my SHA-1 keys to google cloud platform.
one is for debug version and another one is for release version ( same API key with different SHA-1 keys )
my debug version is working fine but when i make a signed apk , it doesn't work ! 
i checked google_maps_api.xml file and it's fine ( i have it on debug and also on main folders of the app )
i added my api key to AndroidManifestes with "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" and also tied "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" but still not working !

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide 2 keys in AndroidManifest.xml file for using google map and google api.

```
<!--Google MAP API key-->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_map_key" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
```

These 2 keys should be generated in [Get an API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key).

If you use the api keys in production mode, you have to [restrict the API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key) before using it in production.

Comment: my bad , i did it again and now its working fine ... thanks alot

Comment: I am happy to hear that!